# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"

Tags: java, long-integer, biginteger

I'm writing a Java program to do some computation on big prime numbers, I get this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:338)
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:476)
    at Solution.sumOfDivisorsModulo(Solution.java:24)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:49)`

```
public static BigInteger sumOfDivisorsModulo(BigInteger n){
    BigInteger sum = (n.add(one)).mod( MODULO);
    for (BigInteger test = n.subtract(one); test.compareTo(new BigInteger(Double.toString(Math.sqrt(n.longValue())))) >= 0; test.subtract(one))
    {
            if(n.mod(test).compareTo(zero) == 0)
            {
                    sum = sum.add(test);
                    sum = sum.add(n.divide(test));
                    sum = sum.mod(MODULO);
            }
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 2;
        int a = 0;
        primeList = new BigInteger[m];
        fillList(m); // fills the list primeList with prime number up to the mth
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger("1");
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
                n.multiply(primeList[i].pow(a+i));
        }
        System.out.println(sumOfDivisorsModulo(n).toString()); // base10
}
```

`one` and `zero` are variables defined as `BigInteger("0")` and `BigInteger("1")`.
Can you help me figure out what the problem is? I thank you in advance.

Comment: For me, the error message `NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"` is very clear, especially when trying to create a `BigInteger` with a _double_ value. Maybe you wanted to use `BigDecimal`?

Comment: Why define your own `one` and `zero` when they are built-in? See [`BigInteger.ONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ONE) and [`BigInteger.ZERO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ZERO).

Comment: Also, you do know that `sum.add(test)` and `sum.add(n.divide(test))` won't do anything, right? You forgot to assign the result back to `sum`. You got it right with `sum = sum.mod(MODULO)`.

Comment: And `test.subtract(one)` too!!! And what's the point of `n` and `test` being `BigInteger` when you're just going to `n.longValue()` it? If you start with a value of `n` that exceeds `Long.MAX_VALUE`, how long do you think the loop of counting down by one from `n` is going to run?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here.

```
   new BigInteger(Double.toString(Math.sqrt(n.longValue())))
```

The `Double.toString()` call is going to give you a number string with a decimal point in it.  But the `BigInteger(String)` constructor cannot parse a number string with a decimal point in it.

I don't understand what you are trying to do here, but the square root is liable to be a non-integer value.

If your intention is to convert the floating point (possibly non-integer) square-root value to an integer, then:

```
   // Round towards zero / truncate
   BigInteger.valueOf((long)(Math.sqrt(n.longValue())))
```

or

```
   // Round to nearest
   BigInteger.valueOf((long)(Math.round(Math.sqrt(n.longValue()))))
```

This should be more efficient than going via a string.  And going via an `int` string is liable to overflow sooner.

Note however that for large enough values of `n` the square-root calculation will be noticeably inaccurate.  There is no solution apart from finding or implementing your own `BigInteger` square-root method.  However, if @Andreas is correct and you don't need to use `BigInteger` at all, this is moot.

Comment: I see. Then how can I create a BigInteger variable from a double?

Comment: @Marrakchino That depends. Do you want the `double` value truncated or rounded?

Comment: I got it, in my case I used Math.floor. Thanks.

Comment: Erm ... but Math.floor gives you a `double`.  So how can that work?

Comment: I casted it to (int), then I used String.valueOf()

Comment: @Marrakchino You like going the long way around on everything if you use `String.valueOf(int)` as part of converting an `int` value into a `BigInteger`, when you have [`BigInteger.valueOf(long val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-).

Comment: @StephenC [`new BigInteger(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#constructor.summary) doesn't exist. Use [`BigInteger.valueOf(long val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-).

Comment: Actually there are no contructors of BigInteger from Long, otherwise it would have been easier.

Comment: @Marrakchino But you have the static `valueOf(long)` doing the same thing, and it *is* easy to use.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Andreas. I finally solved it with: `test.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round((Math.sqrt(n.longValue()))))) >= 0`

Comment: @Marrakchino Oh good. Now good luck with all the rest of your errors (see my comments to the question itself).